# What is the syntax

Tags: php

My variable (`$tax_terms`) contain this information:

```
Array
(
    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 120
            [name] => work
            [slug] => work
        )

)
```

I want to display the name. what would be the php syntax to display the name.

Comment: Where do you want to display the name? Could you give some context for how you wish to use this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$tax_terms[5]->name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `$tax_terms` seems to be an array, and the value at the 5th key is an object, you would access `name` as follows:

```
$name = $tax_terms[5]->name;
```

You might wish to call [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/array_values) on the array to force a re-index, since it looks like someone maybe used `unset()` with the original array. Doing so would make accessing the values more logical.

For example:

```
$tax_terms = array_values($tax_terms);
$name = $tax_terms[0]->name;
```

Comment: Why should the question be closed? He's provided all information and asked a valid question...

Comment: some time ago there were an option too low quality.its very primary to  php,any one who is going to learn php would be aware of that.

Comment: Not necessarily. The fact that the array keys were different and so forth might have been confusing. I can't see a valid reason to close. Just because it's a simple question that a veteran PHP coder could answer, doesn't mean it's any less valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$tax_terms[5]->name
```